# background image swap full screen

Tags: javascript

I'm using a background image swap that changes every refresh.
It works fine, the body tag has the onLoad function. But I want the image to be scaled correctly, now I only get a piece of the image. Anyone any ideas for the scaling?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomize(min, max) {
        if (!min)
            min = 0;
        if (!max)
            max = 1;
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1)+min);
    }
    function randomBg() {
        var bgs = new Array();
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg1.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg2.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg3.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg4.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg5.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg6.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg7.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg8.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg9.jpg");
        bgs.push("images/bg/bg10.jpg");
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + bgs[randomize(0, bgs.length-1)] + ")";
    }
</script>
```

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this article http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image

Comment: Wouldn't a css `background-size: 100% 100%` do the job?

Comment: @JimBlackler, you should definitely turn that into an answer...

Comment: @agryson it doesn't seem right for just pasting a link I found in seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CSS [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size#Syntax).
(`document.body.style.backgroundSize = ''`)

This will make a background stratch to fill the document, even when resizing the window:

```
document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100% 100%';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
```

Comment: if i use
document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
or
document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100%'
I get what I want, but when resizing the browser window I get a repeat that I don't want..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-repeat#Syntax
Disable background-repeating.

Comment: I tried the no repeat, that fixes the repeat, but still when rescaling the window, instead of repeat, it's just white space, any solutions for that?

Comment: `backgroundSize = '100% 100%';`

Comment: tried, that, but didn't work because the page content was small
added html {width: 100%;height: 100%;} to my css and works now! thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you want to mark this answer as the answer, if this works for you?

Comment: document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'; fixes the problem of stretching

Comment: sorry to bother, but can I add something to the code that says to the image to move a bit when resizing the window? so that the most important part of the image, the center piece is in view?