# Position and Slider (see image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: Problems and everything else]

Hi Stackoverflow,

I have some questions.

1) The image behind the black circle will be a full-width responsive slider. How can I put this image behind all the elements, in a way that Internet Explorer doesn't bug everything?

I know I can use position: absolute with z-index, but since I always had problems with IE and positions, I don't know (really), a better solution.

2) The background image of the black circle is also from the slider. Each BG it's directly linked with a image. Example: this colourful image will be linked to this black circle bg. Next slider will be another image with another bg.

How can I do this? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the black circle doesn't change, what I did was: putting the black circle and the background image in a same image. And I just had to "control" the position of the text. It was a dumb solution, but it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

As you said, set the **position** and **z-index** to the black image and append the same to **body** of the html page. Then change the slider images as earlier.

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

put the background image as a DIV and the next DIV "contents" will have all the contents
 eg:

```
            ----contents ----

        </div>

     CSS 

    #bg-image { 
       background: url('http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSsYV2xklhQlwOFsqPY8OrL69n2F_naug6eShy67xcKm6QRFWmqXw');
       background-size: cover;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       overflow: hidden;
    }

    #contents { 
       background: none;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Take a look here [Background image swap full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627648/background-image-swap-full-screen)

> -- Other option is, Make a large size image and place it on background.
>
> -- This is with css. Check this link [perfect full page background image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: I think this is cool, BUT, the background image is not fixed, I'll use the Nivo Slider. So it will be a little tricky to do that with a background image :P

Comment: @starkbr Ya, Sure if you manage to do with nivo. That is good. Main thing is you problem get solution. 
and if you think my answer is correct according to your asked question. make it an answer.